# How to pass variable to a function declared in another function

Tags: php, laravel

When trying to return a stream download in laravel, I need to pass a variable to the function that's declared in `streamDownload`. I must be missing something very basic here.

```
return response()->streamDownload(function () {
    echo base64_decode(DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($VARIABLE_TO_PASS, 'C128'));
}, 'barcode.png');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is when you put your output in your function with use? So when you have an external variable.

```
$VARIABLE_TO_PASS = "mystring";

return response()->streamDownload(function () use ($VARIABLE_TO_PASS) {
    echo base64_decode(DNS1D::getBarcodePNG($VARIABLE_TO_PASS, 'C128'));
}, 'barcode.png');
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The variable is out of scope when using an anonymous function.

You simply pass the variable into the function with the `use` keyword to make it available inside the anonymous function.

```
return response()->streamDownload(function() use ($VARIABLE_TO_PASS) {
```